# Как установить bash на Windows 10 home edition?

Tags: linux, bash, windows-10

Все мануалы говорят, что после активации режима разработчика нужно включить в `optionalfeatures.exe` `Windows Subsystem for Linux`. Но на `HomeEdition` такого нет.

Comment: а anniversary update уже накатили?

Comment: @KoVadim не нашел где и как его нужно накатить

Comment: вообще то он сам должен прийти, но можно и скачать https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, помогло) может переместите помощь в ответ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установить linux подсистему в Windows 10 можно только в том случае, если пришло обновление anniversary update. Оно скорее всего в августе 2016 года должно было само прийти. Если нет - можно попробовать его поставить ручками - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history